# Same domain SMTP unauthenticated message relay

Tags: security, email-server, smtp

While I was doing some testing on an SMTP server I was able to successfully send mail from knownid@myserver.com to knownid@myserver.com through telnet without any authentication. From a risk perspective I think this is a serious concern. But some have views SMTP is designed this way. Anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: Authentication is used for outgoing email from an untrusted IP to an unknown address. If you're coming from a trusted IP, or you're sending to a domain that the server is supposed to accept mail from, authorization is not required.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the SMTP server you are testing is the one setup to handle myserver.com, it's completely normal.

Mail is transferred from server to server unauthenticated.  That's just how SMTP works.  It's only when you expect the server to forward the mail elsewhere for you that you should need to authenticate.

Anyone can connect to the mail server that handles a particular domain and directly send an email to a user at that domain.  If it didn't work that way, you'd have to setup usernames and passwords for hotmail, gmail, yahoo, and a few billion private email domains.  That simply wouldn't work.

Where it is a concern is if it will allow relaying to domains it is NOT supposed to handle.  If you connect to that server and send an email to someoneelse@notmyserver.com, you should need to either be on it's local LAN or authenticate first.

It also doesn't matter what the from email address is.  Though some antispam measures will mark emails sent from the outside using a from address that should only come from the server as spam.